# Find a word and then a value number in string regular expression C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new with regular expression uses, and for 2 days I'm searching how to pull a specific data from a string, but without success.

This string is a partial from a longer string, I need to find a parameter and then get its value:

```
\rRoll Off = 0.25\rSINE = OFF\rSymbol Rate = 1.000000\rBit Rate = 1.322253
```

***Goal***: find the parameter **Symbol Rate** and get its value **1.000000** (need to store just the value) by regular expression using C#.

It will be very helpful if someone can help me with that issue.

Thank you!

Comment: is `\r` a lietral `\r` or carriage return?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Lookbehind

Use this:

```
var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?<=Symbol Rate\s*=\s*)[0-9.]+");
string resultString = myRegex.Match(yourString).Value;
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=Symbol Rate\s*=\s*)` asserts that what precedes is `Symbol Rate`, optional whitespace, `=`, optional whitespace
- `[0-9.]+` one or more chars that are digits or a period

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Look behind must be fixed length. `*` is not allowed.

Comment: @Braj Lookbehind is infinite in .NET

Comment: Wow I was not aware about it. +1 from my side.

Comment: @Braj The only engines I know that allow infinite lookbehind are .NET, Matthew Barnett's `regex` module for Python, and JGSoft (which you can use in EditPadPro for instance but not in a programming language)

Comment: That is great! thank you. And I also learned something new about that lookbehind option.

Comment: +1 for taking liberty of .Net regex engine that allows variable length lookbehind :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using groups...

```
var foo = "\rRoll Off = 0.25\rSINE = OFF\rSymbol Rate = 1.00000\rBit Rate = 1.322253";
var match = Regex.Match(foo, @"Symbol Rate\s*=\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mKK2RU)